# GeForce 600M drivers for Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

I have to buy a new laptop, but I need it to run XP because of some ancient software. My options come with 600M series graphic cards and I can't find anywhere drivers for these on Windows XP. I guess XP won't be able to recognize the gpu. Is there a way to enable this graphic card there? Would Win7 drivers work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run Windows 7, and for the software you still need Windows XP you could use either Windows XP Mode (available from Windows 7 Pro and up) or VirtualBox / VMware.

Windows XP is end of life and should no longer be used.